# Is there a way to see all the versions of a file using git?

Tags: git

I often have a need to find something I coded in an old version of script but I don't know when. I usually try to jump around in the log finding different versions and seeing if they have the change, or I just give up and try something else.

What would be particularly useful is a command that outputs every version of a file between two dates or hashes. Then an easy grep would find what I'm looking for.

It would probably work something like this:

```
git showeverything d612905a..b39af32e /path/to/file /tmp/output
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git has the perfect tool for this: [`git log -S`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) which will search for a change and only show those commits

```
# search changes in all branches which touch the string $abc in a file
git log -p -S'$abc' --all -- path/to/file
```

Comment: That's getting closer, but we're still dealing with changelog output. That's useful, but not as useful as getting the complete raw file related to the change. The main use case is this: I write a function, decide not to use it, forget when I wrote it. Months later I recall the name and want to grep the history for the function and easily cut and paste it without changelog plusses and minuses getting in the way.

Comment: @Matt: first find the commit using `git log -S`, then use `git show <commit-id>`. I guess there's no easy, direct and fast way to do it in one step

Answer (score 0):

I understand this may not be the answer you're looking for, but every git hosting website/service has a nice GUI do look through the commit history of every file in a repository. I use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log [commit_range/dates/other_constraints] -- <filename(s)>` to show all changelogs pertaining to a specific file, and you can add contraints to the dates/commits/etc. as well.

Use `git show <same stuff>` to actually show the files at each stage...

Comment: That's close, but what I'm really interested in is seeing a set of complete files rather than just changelogs between them.

Comment: anwser by @knittl may be what you're looking for, then

Answer (score 0):

`git log file` shows the commit ids for all commits that affected *file*.

`git show commitid:file` prints the contents of the relevant version of the file to stdout.

Note that in the `git show` command, if you just specify the file name is relative to the root of your git repository unless you specify a path, not to your current directory.  To show a file in the current directory:

`git show commitid:./file*`

Comment: I think the answer probably will be a shellscript that takes the git log output and feeds it through git show.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers, I got this:

```bash
for hash in $(git log --pretty=format:%h style/elevation.mss); do 
    echo -e "==========\n$hash\n"
    git show ${hash}:style/elevation.mss
done | less
```

It needs some parametrization, but you get the idea.